# Problem with Cython cell in Spyder editor on MacOS

Tags: macos, cython, spyder

The following code works fine in the Spyder console but not when executed from the Spyder editor.

```
#%load_ext cython

#%%cython
cpdef foo(int x):
    return x
#%%

print(foo(3))
```

When executing this code, the error points to the cpdef line.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) If you want to develop Cython code in Spyder, you need to name your files with the extension `.pyx` (e.g. `test_cython.pyx`). In that case you don't need to write `%load_ext Cython` in your file, simply the content below it. After that, when you run it with `F5` or the menu `Run > Run`, Spyder will know how to execute it and you'll see the call to `print(foo(3))` works as expected.

*Note*: Unfortunately, cells don't work on Cython files, but we'll fix that limitation in Spyder 4, to be released in 2019.